# Using feedparser to get each unique item from a blog. Checking list membership in a for loop not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, feedparser

For whatever reason when I am checking for membership of an item in a list it is saying that none of the items is in the list. However, whenever I print the item it is showing all of the said items. I have tried this with both lists and sets. What am I doing wrong?

```
import feedparser
rss = feedparser.parse("https://website.com/feed")
new_posts = []
date_time = set()

for entry in rss.entries:
    if entry not in new_posts:
        new_posts.append(entry.published)
        print("added")


for entry in rss.entries:
    if entry in new_posts:
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")
```

output:

```
added
added
added
added
added
added
added
added
added
added
added
added
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
```

Answer (score 0):

You're appending `entry.published` to `new_posts` when `entry` is not in `new_posts`. You should append `entry` itself to `new_posts` instead.

Change:

```
new_posts.append(entry.published)
```

to:

```
new_posts.append(entry)
```

Comment: entry.published is the date in which the item was published. Entry itself is the entire blog posts, which is significantly more data.

Comment: `if entry.published in new_posts:`

The above is the code I actually needed for the second loop.

The one I had written before was 

`if entry in new_posts:`

So you were on the right track and thank you, your comment helped me figure it out.